Windows Podman v5.3.1 FATAL: password authentication failed for user
Commands I ran.
podman run --name internet-archive -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -d postgres:12-alpine
podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                 COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                   NAMES
65f84e3684cd  docker.io/library/postgres:12-alpine  postgres    33 minutes ago  Up 33 minutes  0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp  internet-archive
podman exec -it internet-archive createdb --username=root --owner=root crawler
podman start internet-archive
I attempt to conect:
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -d crawler
I get prompted for password. I input it carefully, I get:
'psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"'
I run the following command to check the rules:
podman exec -it internet-archive cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust


The pg_hba.conf you show has trust as auth method for all access so a password would not be required. That leads me to believe you are actually attempting a connection to another instance of Postgres. In other words localhost is not where you think it is.

I used your command-line but with -p 95432:5432 (my laptop port 5432 is in use already) and it worked just fine. Adrian is probably right, but just to check try podman exec -it internet-archive psql -U root and make sure you can connect like that.

@AdrianKlaver Yeah, I had another old instance running that I totally forgot, now that.
